# How to fetch the matched items using awk and regexp?

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to parse "/boot/grub/grubenv" but really not very good at regexp.

Suppose the content of /boot/grub/grubenv is:

```
saved_entry=1
```

I want to output the number "1", like below. I am currently using "awk", but open to other tools.

```
$ awk '/^(saved_entry=)([0-9]+)/ {print $2}' /boot/grub/grubenv
```

But obviously not working, thanks for the help.

Comment: $2 is not related to the regex in this case; it means the second field on the line.  By default, awk splits on whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a field separator with `-F` option:

```
awk -F= '/^saved_entry=/ {print $2}' /boot/grub/grubenv
```

`$1`, `$2`, .. here represents fields (separated by `=`), not a backreferences to captured groups.

Comment: @user180574  Take some care if line has more data like this: `echo "more=2 less=4" | awk -F= '/^more/ {print $2}'` gives `2 less`.  If its only number you are dealing with this can be fixed by a `+` like this `{print +$2}` and it will give only `2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match things probably best to use `match`!
This will work even if there are more fields after and does not need you to change the field separator(incase you are doing any other stuff with the data).

The only drawback of this method is that it will only match the left-most match of the record, so if the data appears twice in the same record(line) then it will only match the first one it finds.

```
  awk 'match($0,/^(saved_entry=)([0-9]+)/,a){print a[2]}' file
```

#### Example

input

```
saved_entry=1 blah blah more stuff
```

output

```
1
```

#### Explanation

Matches the regex in `$0`(the record) and then stores anything in brackets as separate array elements.

From the example, there would be these outputs

`a[0]` is `saved_entry=1`
`a[1]` is `saved_entry=`
`a[2]` is `1`